# Grails controller unit test - injected object is null

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, grails, dependency-injection, spock

I'm using Spock to test a grails controller.  In the controller:

```
def submitUserRegistration() { 
    loginService.sudoAsAppAdmin { // sudoAsAppAdmin is a method that accepts a closure
```

In the test:

```
    LoginService loginService = Mock()
    loginService.sudoAsAppAdmin(_) >> { args -> args[0].call() }
    controller.loginService = loginService
    // other setup
    controller.submitUserRegistration() == null
```

Result:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sudoAsAppAdmin() on null object
```

I can't post the whole project or probably even the whole controller.  Any idea what I can try to fix this?